# Use Entity Framework to insert into a table with no cache(using SQL sequences)

Tags: sql, entity-framework

I have a problem with SQL sequence, and it's the first time when i use it.
There is something about  [sql sequence](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx) , and about [NOCACHE parameter](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v10/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.sqls.doc/sqls270.htm).

I have created a sequence in SQL with no cache, because i always need that my index to be consecutive(and the big problem is that i need his primary key value after the insert, so i could create and insert a new object into another table).
This is my sequence, which also should autoincrement:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE TestSequence
AS INT
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1
NO CACHE
```

And this is my table, with myTableId - primary key

```
 CREATE TABLE database.dbo.myTable
            (myTableId INT NOT NULL,
         name VARCHAR(10))
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.myTable
ADD DEFAULT NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.TestSequence FOR myTableId
GO
```

When i make an insert statement in sql works perfectly(i also restart my sql connection, and after that myTableId didn't jumped on numbers), but when i'm insert from .net, it seems like it does not recognize the autoincrement:

- at the first insert, the index get the value 0 (??? it should be 1), and after that i get this error: 
  "Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_myTable'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.myTable'. The duplicate key value is (0).\r\n The statement has been terminated."

  Because the second object has the same myTableId as the first one.
  This is my code:

  ```
   myTable myNewObject = new myTable{name = "dada"};
    _db.myTable.Add(myNewObject);
    _db.SaveChanges();
   int id = myNewObject.myTableId; //here i'm getting the foreign-key value that i need
  ```

I don't know if it's relevant, but I'm using SQL 2012 and MVS 2012 ( Entity Framework )

Do you have any idea where is my mistake or what i'm missing? Thank you